# Python: How to aggregate and count identical values in a Dictionary

Tags: python

I'm using a defaultdict from Python's collections:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
```

Within the dictionary I have a set of key/list. Example:

```
{1: [1, 6, 3, 4, 5], 2: [1, 3, 2, 4, 5], 3: [1, 6, 3, 4, 5]})
```

I'm looking for a way to count how many times each list (identical order and content) is found in the dictionary. Basically, I need to aggregate each list with a counter.
For example, the combination [1, 6, 3, 4, 5] is found 2 times.
Is there any helper class/function that can do it? Other than that, I'd just create a double for loop across the dictionary.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter
data = defaultdict(list, {1: [1, 6, 3, 4, 5], 2: [1, 3, 2, 4, 5], 3: [1, 6, 3, 4, 5]})
c = Counter(map(tuple, data.values()))

print(c)

Counter({(1, 6, 3, 4, 5): 2, (1, 3, 2, 4, 5): 1})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It even orders items by frequency, that's awesome. Ps cannot find "collection", I'd assume that's a typo

Comment: you're welcome. thanks for the edit, didn't notice that, just added the imports afterwards and failed at copy paste :P

Answer (score 1):

```
H = {1: [1, 6, 3, 4, 5], 2: [1, 3, 2, 4, 5], 3: [1, 6, 3, 4, 5]}
occurences = dict()
for i in H.keys() :
    k = 0
    for j in H.keys():
        if H[j] == H[i] :
            k += 1 
    if i not in occurences.keys():
        occurences[i] = k
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = {1: [1, 6, 3, 4, 5], 2: [1, 3, 2, 4, 5], 3: [1, 6, 3, 4, 5]}
>>> print(Counter(tuple(l) for l in d.values())
Counter({(1, 6, 3, 4, 5): 2, (1, 3, 2, 4, 5): 1})
```

You'll have to convert your lists to tuples, because Counters can't count unhashable (mutable) types.